# How to insert a hash inside a hash ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I was wondering how I could insert a hash into another hash. For example, in:

```
{"abcd"=>{}, "hgfe"=>34567}
```

I want to put `"hgfe" => 34567` into the `"abcd"` key.

output:

```
{"abcd"=>{"hgfe" => 34567}}
```

im wanting to convert this hash

"##### RUBY HASH ####

(1)

INPUT

```
{
  'abcd.hgfe' => 34567,
  'abcd.efgh.hijk' => 12345,
  'abcd.efgh.ijkl' => 56789,
  'wxyz.abcd' => 9876,
  'wxyz.uvwx.abcd' => 23456,
}
```

(1)

OUTPUT

```
{
  'abcd' => {
    'efgh' => {
      'hijk' => 12345,
      'ijkl' => 56789
    },
    'hgfe' => 34567,
   },
  'wxyz' => {
    'abcd' => 9876,
    'uvwx' => {'abcd' => 23456}
  }
}
```

"

my currrent code:

```
def method1(hash)
  result = {}
  array2 = []

  hash.each_pair do|k, v|
    array1 = k.split('.')
    count = array1.length
    hash2 = {}

    array1.each_with_index do |str, index|

        if (index + 1) == count
            hash2[str] = v
        else
            hash2[str] = {} 


        end

    end

    puts hash2.inspect
    puts "--------------"

  end

  result

end


hash_result = method1(h2c)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do as below

```
hash = {"abcd"=>{}, "hgfe"=>34567}
hash['abcd']['hgfe'] = hash.delete('hgfe')
hash # => {"abcd"=>{"hgfe"=>34567}}
```

You can write something like below :

```
def delete_key_and_add_to_another_key(hash, update_key, del_key)
  hash[update_key][del_key] = hash.delete(del_key)
  hash
end

hash = {"abcd"=>{}, "hgfe"=>34567}
delete_key_and_add_to_another_key(hash, 'abcd', 'hgfe')
```

Comment: what if its general... like it can be any key.... like if you want to change the input everytime?

Comment: @RedondoVelasco Wrap the logic inside the method.. And use it.

Comment: @RedondoVelasco this is why you should ask *specific* questions. Include your real input and the desired output and describe the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

```
h = {"abcd"=>{}, "hgfe"=>34567}
f, l = h.partition { |_,v| v =={} }.flatten(1)
{ f.first=> { l.first => l.last } }
  #=> {"abcd"=>{"hgfe"=>34567}}
```